# Monitoring a port's USB, without WinForm, just only Console Application

Tags: c#, events, console-application

I'm learning C# and I need help, please.
My question: how to know whether a USB-disk has been mounted/unmounted?
I found an answer for WndProd

```
    const int WM_DEVICECHANGE           = 0x0219;
    const int DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL         = 0x8000; 
    const int DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE  = 0x8004;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DEV_BROADCAST_HDR
    {
        public int dbch_size;
        public int dbch_devicetype;
        public int dbch_reserved;
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_DEVICECHANGE)
        {
            int EventCode = m.WParam.ToInt32();
            Log(string.Format("WM_DEVICECHANGE. Код={0}", EventCode));

            switch (EventCode)
            {
                case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
                {
                    Log("Добавление устройства");
                    break;
                }
                case DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE:
                {
                    Log("Удаление устройства");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        base.WndProc (ref m);

    }
```

and this version

```
public class WMIReceiveEvent
    {
        public WMIReceiveEvent()
        {
            try
            {
                WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DeviceChangeEvent");

                ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(query);
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for an event...");

                watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(HandleEvent);

                // Start listening for events
                watcher.Start();

                // Do something while waiting for events
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);

                // Stop listening for events
                //watcher.Stop();
                //return;
            }
            catch (ManagementException err)
            {

            }
        }

        private void HandleEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Win32_DeviceChangeEvent event occurred.   "+ e.NewEvent.ClassPath.ClassName.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("2_Win32_DeviceChangeEvent event occurred.   " + e.NewEvent.Properties.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }            

    }
```

but I would like version for **DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL** and **DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE** without WinForm. Because for WndProc need **System.Windows.Form** and Class must be the successor "**:Form**"
And for WMIReceiveEvent not the best solution for my task.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NativeWindow` instead of `Form` and still use `WndProc(ref Message msg)`.
It's practically an invisible form, see example:

```
[System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
public class MyMessageHandler : NativeWindow
{
    private event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> messageReceived;
    public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> MessageReceived
    {
        add
        {
            if (messageReceived == null || !messageReceived.GetInvocationList().Contains(value))
                messageReceived += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            messageReceived -= value;
        }
    }

    public MyMessageHandler()
    {
        var cp = new CreateParams();
        CreateHandle(cp);
    }

    [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message msg)
    {
        var handler = messageReceived;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new MyEventArgs(msg));

        base.WndProc(ref msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: I really hoped this technique would work, but unfortunately the console application only receives a few message events, and WM_DEVICECHANGE is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with writing a Console application for this is that it doesn't have a message loop (at least, not by default; you would have to write your own).

The simpler solution is to create a Windows Forms project, but just don't show any forms. You would essentially be creating a "background" application that doesn't display any user interface. WinForms applications provide a message pump for you automatically, allowing you to catch the messages you're interested in.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. and how to write a message loop yourself? or how to use "background" application in ConsoleApp if it is  the successor ":Form" ? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the requirements of your application you might as well do polling. You build a loop checking all possible drive letters like

> System.IO.Directory.Exists(driveLetter);

and compare it to an existing drive letter array or struct or whatever. Create an event as soon as they are different.

That would be the easy way though not as fantastic regarding performance. But as I said, it depends on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your example is very interesting and easily realizable.
But I would like to gain experience with messaging the system. But unfortunately very little training material on the network 
Understandable for non-experienced